# Provide UserName<553> message in quick

Tags: quickfix

I have created an application for FIX transactions using QuickFIX c++ API. The application is connecting to the server but the server sends "Provide UserName<553>" message. I looked for and result and found that i need to add username and password to the toAdmin method created this following code to in order to achieve that

```
void Application::toAdmin( FIX::Message& message, const FIX::SessionID& sessionID)
{
    if (FIX::MsgType_Logon == message.getHeader().getField(FIX::FIELD::MsgType))
    {
        FIX44::Logon& logon_message = dynamic_cast<FIX44::Logon&>(message);
        logon_message.setField(FIX::Username("my_username"));
        logon_message.setField(FIX::Password("my_password"));
    }
}
```

But then it throws and Exception. Please suggest what to do

Comment: And the exception is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line and exception is handled

```
   FIX44::Logon& logon_message = dynamic_cast<FIX44::Logon&>(message);
```

after that Put it

**message.setField(FIX::Username("my_username"));
  ```````
    message.setField(FIX::Password("my_password"));**